# How to edit a specific JButton's data

Tags: java, swing, layout, multidimensional-array, jbutton

I have this code:

```
 JButton[][] grid;
    grid = new JButton[15][13];
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = new JButton("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            frame.add(grid[x][y]);
        }
    }
```

My question is, how do I edit a specific JButton? Let's say I want to add different text to the JButton at [2][2]. Ultimately, I'd like to add other things like an actionlistener and such to the button, but my primary question is how to access a specific button.

Comment: grid[2][2].setText("Hello");    ??

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use grid?  (your array)

Answer (score 2):

you can just use `grid[2][2]` to get the button, just like to access a normal two-dimension array.